# how to add a hostname into trust server certificate in subversion?

Tags: svn

I did some research for this topic, and I find sth like this,
http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_subversion_to_trust_a_given_ssl_certificate.html
what tell me how to solve my problem, so I did as it says.
I create a pem file called example.pem by:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/example.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/certs/example.key -days 3650 -subj '/CN=my_hostname'
```

and changed the servers file at ~/.subversion/servers

```
[global] ssl-authority-files = /etc/ssl/certs/example.pem
```

everything is done, but when I try to execute the cmd like 'svn list my_hostname'
I got `Error validating server certificate for 'my_hostname'`
again.
Can anyone be pleased to tell me, what can I do to solve my problem.